# Animate by decimal values

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

```
var Y = 0.2; // Motion step
var X = 0.6;

(function go(){

  $('#m').animate({
    left: '+='+(X) ,
    top:  '+='+(Y)     
  }, 30, 'linear', go);

}());
```

Move an element diagonally but not under 45° (Y=1, X=1), rather by steps of a floated number. 
Mozilla plays well, but all other browser won't move an element by a decimal *px* value.

What approach would you use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of trying to do it through recursion, why not set the left and top values as integers and do it in one animate() call.  This way you don't have to deal with floating point numbers and it should still animate diagonally.

```
var Y = 20; // cannot be >1
var X = 60; // cannot be >1

    function go(){

      $('#m').animate({
        left: '+='+(X) ,
        top:  '+='+(Y)     
      }, 300, 'linear');

    }
    go();
```

Answer (score 1):

A pixel is, by definition, the smallest element that can be displayed (or not displayed) at the current screen resolution. You can use % and I believe it will work cross browser eg width: 45.5%, but pixels no. In addition you may not even notice the movement that small.

Comment: That is not strictly true. Many modern browsers, Firefox included, perform calculations with elements that have `real`/`float` dimensions

Comment: As you can see in my demo in Firefox the movement inside the loop is noticeable as hell!

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that when you're setting left and top they're getting rounded to pixels. You're seeing 45-degree motion because both X and Y get rounded to 1.

Why don't you increment two JS variables (which can store floating-point numbers) and then set left and top equal to them at the appropriate time (so the rounding will occur on the sum and not on the increment)?

```
var Y = 0.2; // cannot be >1
var X = 0.6; // cannot be >1

var cur_left = $('#m').left;
var cur_top = $('#m').top;

function go(){
  cur_left += X;
  cur_top += Y;
  $('#m').animate({
    left: '='+(cur_left),
    top:  '='+(cur_top)     
  }, 30, 'linear', go);
}
go();
```

Comment: although your changed code won't work -- I'm really thinking about your suggestion to write a function that will fire both X and Y only after the number is rounded. I'll think about that +1 thanks for the tips and suggestions

Comment: Yeah, sorry -- didn't test it and my jquery is very rusty -- but something along those lines will likely solve the problem. Glad I could help!